# Does SignalR can reuse active connections to server other users

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr

I want to know  SignalR per-server connection limitations. Let's say that my mobile app is starting a connection to the server. The app is idle for let's say 5 minutes (not data is send from a specific client to the server nor from the server to a specific client, does SignalR can use that connection to serve other users, or SignalR creates a separate connection for each user?

I want to know whether I should use SignalR or just call the server every few seconds. My mobile app will be running in the background on the user's mobile phone and might be active on the user's mobile phone all day long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR has 1 connection for every user and the amount of connections you can have open at a given time completely depends on the server implementation, hardware etc.

If your app does not rely on real-time data then polling is an appropriate approach.  However if you do want nearly real-time data then I'd argue that polling every 2-3 can be just as taxing as maintaining an open connection.

As a final note SignalR can be configured to poll via its Long Polling transport but it will still maintain a connection object on the server, the request just wont be held onto. That way SignalR can keep track of all the users and will ensure that users get the messages that were sent to them.